# Angular ignores Set Cookie and Delete Cookie headers with CORS

Tags: angular, express, cookies, https, cross-domain

Each request is populated with a `WithCredentialsInterceptor`:

```
@Injectable()
export class WithCredentialsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

In the back:

`CORS` middleware:

```
// process.env.CLIENT = https://www.example.com
this.router.options('*', cors({origin: process.env.CLIENT, credentials: true}));

this.router.use(cors({origin: process.env.CLIENT, credentials: true}));

// On valid Login:
res.cookie('SESSIONID', createdSession, {maxAge: someTime, httpOnly: true, secure: true});

res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', createdToken, {maxAge: someTime});
```

**In development:** `ng serve --ssl`

1. Using `proxy.conf.json` and NOT `cors` - both cookies were successfully set in the visible "cookie jar" (devtools -> application/storage -> cookies).
2. Removing `proxy.conf.json` in favor of CORS to imitate production architecture sets only the XSRF cookie, but the `SESSIONID` which is flagged `secure` and `httpOnly` is NOT. The headers sent in that case is only `X-XSRF-TOKEN` (I assume this is an expected behavior for a fake `HTTPS` dev-server).
3. Assuming it will work properly inside a legit HTTPS enviromnet, I proceeded with the structure.

The domain names are as follows:

- https://www.example.com => client (cloudfront, valid SSL)
- https://api.example.com => server (ALB, valid SSL)

**The problem**

BOTH cookies are NOT set in the "cookie jar"

ALTHOUGH: 
The cookies are shown in the response headers on a successful login:

**Response Headers:**

```
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=The-legit-XSRF-TOKEN; Max-Age=number; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 22 Oct 2019 18:56:31 GMT
set-cookie: SESSIONID=The-legit-SessionID-Token; Max-Age=number; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 22 Oct 2019 18:56:31 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure
```

And they are also SENT in the next request:

**Request Headers**

```
cookie: SESSIONID=The-legit-SessionID-Token; XSRF-TOKEN=The-legit-XSRF-TOKEN
```

But the `XSRFInterceptor` does NOT capture the cookie it should, nor is it available via `document.cookie`, therefore the request is NOT sent with the `X-XSRF-TOKEN`.

`XSRFInterceptor` implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenExtractor: HttpXsrfTokenExtractor) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Obse rvable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const HEADER_NAME = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
    // let TOKEN = document.cookie.split('; ').find(cookie => cookie.startsWith('XSRF-TOKEN'));
    let TOKEN = this.tokenExtractor.getToken() as string;
    if (TOKEN && !req.headers.has(HEADER_NAME)) {
      // TOKEN = TOKEN.split('=')[1];
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.append(HEADER_NAME, TOKEN) });
    }
    console.log(req) // <-- withCredentials: true
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

In my server logs, I receive the affirmation the cookies are well received, but as the `XSRFInterceptor` failed to extract the token, the middleware knocks down my request:

```
console.log(csrfCookie, csrfHeader); // The-legit-XSRF-TOKEN, undefined

console.log(csrfCookie === csrfHeader); // false
```

I managed to log in by copying a legit `SESSIONID` and `XSRF-TOKEN` into the cookie jar and when trying to log out - I noticed Angular also ignores a `DELETE cookie` headers sent from the server, as I was progrematically transferred to the login page, though the copied cookies were NOT deleted.

Anyone recognizes this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

In `res.cookie` I added `domain: '.example.com'`.

Without any domain specification, at dev environment it defaulted to `localhost` which is the same in both ends. But in production, I guess it defaulted to `api.example.com` and as it did not align with the origin url `www.example.com`, the browser did not treat it as something that has to be placed in the jar.